# Function with PWideChar parameter taking only first char

Tags: string, delphi, opengl, pointers, char

I've just encountered a weird problem. I am trying to load a model to OpenGL and in the part where I load textures I use `auxDIBImageLoadA(dibfile:PWideChar)` function. Here is my code calling it

```
procedure CreateTexture(var textureArray: array of UINT; strFileName: string; textureID: integer);       // Vytvožení textury
var
  pBitmap: PTAUX_RGBImageRec;                                                   
begin
  if strFileName = '' then exit;                                                
  MessageBox(0,PWideChar(strFileName),nil,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
  pBitmap := auxDIBImageLoadA(PWideChar(strFileName));      
  if pBitmap = nil then exit;    
...
```

The MessageBox is just for control. This is what happens: I run the application, a box with `"FACE.BMP"` appears. Okay. But then I get an error saying `"Failed to open DIB file F"`. When i set the `stFileName` to `xFACE.BMP`, I get an `"Failed to open DIB file x"`. So for some reason it appears that the function is taking only the first char.

Am I missing something? I'm using glaux.dll which I downloaded like 5 times from different sources, so it should be bug-free (I hope, every OpenGL site referred to it).

Comment: WideChar `'F'` represented as two AnsiChars `'F', #0`, and here you are, truncated string

Comment: always write your delphi version please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's odd, functions ending in "A" generally take PAnsiChar pointers, and those ending in "W" take PWideChar pointers. Is there a `auxDIBImageLoadW` call also? If there is use that one, or try with PAnsiChar, since the PWideChar you pass (two bytes per position) would look like a string one character long if it is evaluated as a 1-byte string.

Comment: The function takes PChar. There is no other alternative, at least in the unit I've found. Also, the example is for Delphi7, I have Delphi XE and I'm getting errors because there are calls for `MessageBox(..,PAnsiChar)` while Delphi XE knows `MessageBox(.., PWideChar)` . Is calling `MessageBox(PWidechar(pansicharparam))` ok?

Comment: I think MessageBoxA and MessageBoxW exist also. It's 'usual' to have a function call declaration, without suffix, forwarding to one of both depending on the 'platform standard' (which changed in Delphi 2006 or thereabouts) but I would suggest to select AnsiChar/WideChar and A/W suffixes all the way to avoid confusion.

Comment: Great! I downloaded a poorly written GLaux.pas file, so I searched for the "original" C++ and found the `auxDIBImageLoadW` function and wrote it to the .pas . It works like a charm now, thank you. But still, how would it be possible to convert PWideChar to PAnsiChar or vice versa?

Comment: Normally PAnsiChar(AnsiString(MyWideString1)) should work and vice versa

Comment: @MagicMaster, It wasn't necessarily badly written. It's probably just pre-dating Delphi 2009. There was no way to know for sure back then that PChar would become an alias of PWideChar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your Unicode string to ANSI. Do it like this

```
pBitmap := auxDIBImageLoadA (PAnsiChar(AnsiString(strFileName)))
```

You would be better off calling the Unicode version though

```
pBitmap := auxDIBImageLoadW (PWideChar(strFileName))
```